# eclipse + pydev autocomplete

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana-studio

Problem:- Autocomplete for python not working in eclipse + pydev. 
Platform:- OS is Lubuntu; Eclipse Version: 4.2.2; PyDev for Eclipse 2.7.3.2013031601

I have configured the pythonpath in "Window->Preferences->Pydev->Interpreter-Python". 
Under this dialog, in the section called "System PYTHONPATH" I clicked on the right-hand button labeled "New Folder" and added the Folder "/var/libs/python-support". 
Clicked 'Apply', restarted eclipse. But still python auto completion doesn't work (ctrl+space).

Any suggestion?

Thanks, 
Vineet
[Screenshot of Preferences in Eclipse](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B19k9LwAcJEQa2hJLXpBTm1nV1U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the interpreter configuration screen?

Comment: I have edited the question to include link for screenshot of preferences in Eclipse.  Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue but I have Eclipse Kepler running on MacOs. When I do Ctrl+Space to autocomplete Eclipse becomes 'not responsive' for a while. I added the flag -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to the eclipse.ini without any positive effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found on my end. I had commented out in my /etc/host file the localhost mapping for some scenario I needed to test with GAE and subdomains.

Adding back the mapping (127.0.0.1    localhost) Pydev auto-complete feature started to work again. Weird that I didn't have this issue with Pydev v2. It seems like Pydev v3 does it different.

So, just make sure localhost is mapped in your /etc/hosts file.